# Not able to retrieve photo captions from newer photos through Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch the user entered caption of a photo from the Graph Explorer in Facebook API. The field as per the documentation is 'name'.
But eventhough I am able to get 'name' for old photos, newly uploaded photos are not returning the 'name' attribute.

Have anyone faced the issue before?
I would appreciate any help on this as I have posted the bug to the Facebook support but have not got the issue resolved yet.
Here is the link to the bug report on Facebook support.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1630340127227943/